# How to add custom column in-between people/users admin page table?

Tags: 7, hooks

I have created a custom column to display last user changed time, but I need this field to be inserted before OPERATIONS column. Below is my code which appends my custom field at the end.

```
function meme_user_update_form_user_admin_account_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $changed_column = array('changed' => array(
    'data'  => 'LAST CHANGED',
    'field' => 'u.changed'
  ));
  $form['accounts']['#header'] = $form['accounts']['#header'] + $changed_column;
  foreach ($form['accounts']['#options'] as $key => $row) {
    $user_object = user_load($key);
    $user_language = ($user_object->language) ? $user_object->language : LANGUAGE_NONE;
    $form['accounts']['#options'][$key]['changed'] = $user_object->field_user_changed[$user_language][0]['value'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the sequence of the array, like:

```
function meme_user_update_form_user_admin_account_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $changed_column = array(
    'data'  => 'LAST CHANGED',
    'field' => 'u.changed'
  );
  $operation_column = array_pop($form['accounts']['#header']);

  $form['accounts']['#header']['changed'] = $changed_column;
  $form['accounts']['#header']['operations'] = reset($operation_column);

  foreach ($form['accounts']['#options'] as $key => $row) {
    $user_object = user_load($key);
    $user_language = ($user_object->language) ? $user_object->language : LANGUAGE_NONE;

    $operation_column = array_pop($form['accounts']['#options'][$key]);

    $form['accounts']['#options'][$key]['changed'] = $user_object->field_user_changed[$user_language][0]['value'];
    $form['accounts']['#options'][$key]['operations']['data'] = reset($operation_column);
  }
}
```

Comment: We can't use array_pop or array_push in a keyed associative array i.e in our case array_pop will only get the value not the entire array with key, also array push will push the new array with key 0.

Comment: so use reset - i updated my answer

Comment: No change even after using reset.  The array looks like below  [access] => Array
        (
            [data] => Last access
            [field] => u.access
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [changed] => Array
                (
                    [data] => LAST CHANGED
                    [field] => u.changed
                )

        )

    [operations] => Operations

Comment: okey -- again updated my question and made it work for you !

Answer (score 1):

You could switch to the [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module and customize the entire view, including using the [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module, if you wanted.

> Replaces administrative overview/listing pages with actual views for
>   superior usability.

This is a very similar pattern to the way administrative pages work in Drupal 8, where views are core entities.